# Check for function called

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Just wondering if there is anyway to fire some code when a function is called, without adding the code to the function, for example:

```
function doSomething(){
    //Do something
}

//Code to call when doSomething is called
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the function :

```
(function(){
   var oldFunction = doSomething;
   doSomething = function(){
       // do something else
       oldFunction.apply(this, arguments);
   }
})();
```

I use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) here just to avoid polluting the global namespace, it's accessory.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes, it's not actually hard to do. The crucial thing is that a function's name is just an identifier like any other. You can redefine it if you want to.

```
var oldFn = doSomething;
doSomething = function() {
    // code to run before the old function

    return oldFn.apply(this, arguments);

    // code to run after the old function
};
```

NB that it's better to do `oldFn.apply(this, arguments)` rather than just `oldFn`. In many cases it won't matter, but it's possible that the context (i.e. the value of `this` inside the function) and the arguments are important. Using `apply` means they are passed on as if `oldFn` had been called directly.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like:

```
function doSomething(){
     doSomething.called = true;
}

//call?
doSomething();

if(doSomething.called) {
   //Code to call when doSomething is called
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you don't want to modify the original function, but consider adding a callback. Then you can execute code based on different results in your function (such as onSucess and onError):

```
function doSomething(onSuccess, onError){
    try {
        throw "this is an error";
        if(onSuccess) {
            onSuccess();
        }
    } catch(err) {
        if(onError) {
            onError(err);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you call `doSomething`, you can specify what you want done with inline functions:

```
doSomething(function() {
    console.log("doSomething() success");
}, function(err) {
    console.log("doSomething() error: " + err);
});
```